# ChromeOptions not getting applied

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, chrome-options

I am trying to open the chrome browser with devtools open in maximized window.
Following code does not work, driver opens the URL in a smaller window without devtools.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "<path to chrome.exe>");

ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();        
<String> chromeoptions = new ArrayList<String>();
chromeoptions.add("start-maximised");
chromeoptions.add("auto-open-devtools-for-tabs");
options.addArguments(chromeoptions);

WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(options);

driver.get("http://www.google.com");
```

I have also used Capabilities with no result.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.binary", "<path to chrome exe>");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);      
WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

I am using Chrome 75, selenium jar version 3.4.0

Any suggestion?

Comment: Arguments should be `--start-maximized` and not `start-maximised`. You are missing `--` and have a typo in word `maximized`. The same `--` probably applies for the second argument as well

Comment: Thanks Fenio. Did all possible combination. Also corrected spelling. Still no luck.

Comment: Try `driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1920, 1080));`

Comment: Hi Fenio, I changed the driver version to 3.0.0. Started working with the previous code.

Answer (score 2):

As per your code, there have some spelling mistake like("start-maximi**s**ed") instead of ("--start-maximi**z**ed")

kindly use the below code:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
options.addArguments("--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: Hi Amit,I have tried this also with no luck. Can you please tell me what version of the selenium jar you are using. I am thinking that might be the issue.

Comment: I'm using latest version of selenium i.e. 3.14. and it's working fine with me.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I changed selenium version to 3.0.0 and It started working.

Answer (score 0):

Try using chrome options like this. it'll download the correct chrome driver version automatically and also chrome options work correctly.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/');
```